# Configuring a Dedicated Listener Container for each Queue using Spring AMQP Java Configuration

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have listeners configured in XML like this

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" concurrency="1" acknowledge="manual">
    <rabbit:listener ref="messageListener" queue-names="${address.queue.s1}" exclusive="true"/>
    <rabbit:listener ref="messageListener" queue-names="${address.queue.s2}" exclusive="true"/>
    <rabbit:listener ref="messageListener" queue-names="${address.queue.s3}" exclusive="true"/>
    <rabbit:listener ref="messageListener" queue-names="${address.queue.s4}" exclusive="true"/>
    <rabbit:listener ref="messageListener" queue-names="${address.queue.s5}" exclusive="true"/>
    <rabbit:listener ref="messageListener" queue-names="${address.queue.s6}" exclusive="true"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

I am trying to move that to Java Configuration and I don't see a way to add more than one MessageListener to a ListenerContainer. Creating multiple ListenerContainer beans is not an option in my case because I would not know the number of queues to consume from until runtime. Queue names will come from a configuration file.

I did the following

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() 
{
    for (String queue : queues.split(","))
    {
        // The Consumers would not connect if I don't call the 'start()' method.
        messageListenerContainer(queue).start();
    }
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(String queue)
{
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(consumerConnectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queue);
    container.setMessageListener(messageListener());

    // Set Exclusive Consumer 'ON'
    container.setExclusive(true);

    // Should be restricted to '1' to maintain data consistency.
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    return container;
}
```

It "sort" of works BUT I see some weird behavior with lots of ghost channels getting opened which never used to happen with the XML configuration. So it makes me suspicious that I am doing something wrong. I would like to know the correct way of creating MessageListenerContainers in Java configuration? Simply put, "How does Spring convert 'rabbit:listener-container' with multiple 'rabbit:listener' to java objects properly?" Any help/insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

**Business Case**
We have a Publisher that publishes User Profile Updates. The publisher could dispatch multiple updates for the same use and we have to process them in the correct order to maintain data integrity in the data store.

**Example** : User : ABC, Publish -> {UsrA:Change1,...., UsrA:Change 2,....,UsrA:Change 3} -> Consumer HAS to process {UsrA:Change1,...., UsrA:Change 2,....,UsrA:Change 3} in that order.

In our previous setup, we had 1 Queue that got all the User Updates and we had a consumer app with concurrency = 5. There were multiple app servers running the consumer app. That resulted in *5 * '*Number of instances of the consumer app*' channels/threads* that could process the incoming messages. The speed was GREAT! but we were having out of order processing quite often resulting in data corruption.

To maintain strict FIFO order and still process message parallelly as much as possible, we implemented queue Sharding. We have a "x-consistent-hash with a hash-header on employee-id. Our Publisher publishes messages to the hash exchange and we have multiple sharded queues bound to the hash exchange. The idea is, we will have all changes for a given user (User A for example) queued up in the same shard. We then have our consumers connect to the sharded queues in 'Exclusive' mode and 'ConcurrentConsumers = 1' and process the messages. That way we are sure to process messages in the correct order while still processing messages parallelly. We could make it more parallel by increasing the number of shards.

**Now on to the consumer configuration**

We have the consumer app deployed on multiple app servers.

**Original Approach:**

I simply added multiple 'rabbit:listener' to my 'rabbit:listener-container' in my consumer app as you can see above and it works great except for the server that starts first get an exclusive lock on all the sharded queues and the other servers are just sitting there doing no work.

**New Approach:**

We moved the sharded queue names to the application configuration file. Like so

```
Consumer Instance 1 : Properties
queues=user.queue.s1,user.queue.s2,user.queue.s3

Consumer Instance 2 : Properties
queues=user.queue.s4,user.queue.s5,user.queue.s6
```

*Also worth noting, we could have Any number of Consumer instances and the shards could be distributed unevenly between instances depending on resource availability.*

With the queue names moved to configuration file, the XML confiugration will no longer work because we cannot dynamically add 'rabbit:listener' to my 'rabbit:listener-container' like we did before.

Then we decided to switch over to the Java Configuration. That is where we are STUCK!.

*We did this initially*

```
@Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer()
    {

        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(consumerConnectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queues.split(","));
        container.setMessageListener(messageListener());
        container.setMissingQueuesFatal(false);

        // Set Exclusive Consumer 'ON'
        container.setExclusive(true);

        // Should be restricted to '1' to maintain data consistency.
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);

        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
        container.start();

        return container;
    }
```

and it works BUT all our queues are on one connection sharing 1 channel. That is NOT good for speed. What we want is One connection and every queue gets its own channel.

*Next Step*

No success here YET!. The java configuration in my original question is where we are at now.

I am baffled why this is so HARD to do. Clearly the XML configuration does something that is NOT easly doable in Java confiugration (Or atleast it feel sthat way to me). I see this as a gap that needs to be filled unless I am compeltly missing something. Please correct me if I am wrong. This is a genuine business case NOT some ficticious edge case. Please feel free to comment if you think otherwise.

Comment: You can't invoke the same `@Bean` method with different queues - you need a separate `@Bean` definition for each container as the answer below suggests. Also `>messageListenerContainer(queue).start();` - you should **never** do stuff like that in a `@PostConstruct` method; the context will fail to start if the broker is not available.

Comment: Hi Garry, thank you for the response :-).

Comment: @Gary Russell, as you mentioned, I did exactly that and it did not work. I kick off the `@Bean` method invocation in the `@PostConstruct` method. Oddly though, when I did that, the ListenerContainer never starts (Or at least that is my perception because I cannot see any connections in the Rabbit Admin Console.). Then I added the "messageListenerContainer(queue).start();" which worked BUT there are now two connections and the second connection is going crazy trying to connect in the process opening Channels nonstop. This is DEFINITELY not the same as the XML config.

Comment: You need a separate `@Bean` method for each container; you must not invoke those methods from a `@PostConstruct` they must be in a `@Configuration` class and Spring will create the beans.

Comment: @GaryRussell : "You need a separate `@Bean` method for each container". I can do that IF i knew the queue names ahead of time. Like I said, In my case, I don't know the queue names until runtime. Please see my question, I have updated it with our business case and why having a separate `@Bean` method for each container upfront is NOT always possible.

Comment: Your question is now completely different; for your original question, you'd do it the same way as `queue-names="${address.queue.s1}"`, but using `@Value` injection for the queue names for each `@Bean`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173501/discussion-between-rajeev-k-and-gary-russell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and it works BUT all our queues are on one connection sharing 1 channel. That is NOT good for speed. What we want is One connection and every queue gets its own channel.

If you switch to the `DirectMessageListenerContainer`, each queue in that configuration gets its own `Channel`.

[See the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#choose-container).

To answer your original question (pre-edit):

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer1(@Value("${address.queue.s1}") String queue)
{
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(consumerConnectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queue);
    container.setMessageListener(messageListener());

    // Set Exclusive Consumer 'ON'
    container.setExclusive(true);

    // Should be restricted to '1' to maintain data consistency.
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    return container;
}

...

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer6(@Value("${address.queue.s6}" ) String queue)
{
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(consumerConnectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queue);
    container.setMessageListener(messageListener());

    // Set Exclusive Consumer 'ON'
    container.setExclusive(true);

    // Should be restricted to '1' to maintain data consistency.
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    return container;
}
```

Comment: The DirectMessageListenerContainer works. It created a channel per queue just like we wanted. Thank you for pointing that out 

Comment: I noticed when I used the XML config (Which uses SimpleMessageListenerContainer), I got One Connection with as many channels as there are queues.  With the Java Config using the `DirectMessageListenerContainer` I see "Two" Connections. One connection (Started First) has as many channels as there are queues and the second connection (Started later) just has 1 channel and it is NOT listening to any queues. I a not sure how and why this extra connection + channel is created. If I kill it from admin the Rabbit Admin Console, it does NOT seem to come back. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I can't think of anything that would open a second connection, unless you have a second connection factory. I would expect to see an extra channel if there is a `RabbitAdmin` in the application context. What do you see in the connection names in the Admin UI? You should see something like `rabbitConnectionFactory#33308786:0`. Also DEBUG logging should help figure it out.

Comment: I am not using RabbitAdmin. So that is not it. I implemented `connection-name-strategy` so that I can identify which app is connecting and both the connections were showing my consumer app name. I removed it now for testing and now it shows `consumerConnectionFactory#697afcb8:0` for the connection with the right number of channels and the channels ae listening to queues and it shows `consumerConnectionFactory#ba86459:0` for the other second connection with 1 channel that is not listening to anything. I am running my app in DEBUG mode. I can look @ the logs if you can tell me what to look for.

Comment: That looks like the default connection naming strategy and it indicates you have two connection factory instances somehow. The value after the `#` is `ObjectUtils.getIdentityHexString(this)` plus an incrementing int. Look for `Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#33308786:0/SimpleConnection@3542162` in the log (INFO level).

Comment: `2018-06-20 12:31:06 INFO  CachingConnectionFactory:463 - Created new connection: consumerConnectionFactory#70fd04ad:0/SimpleConnection@9ec0f70 [delegate=amqp://rabbituser@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 64641]
2018-06-20 12:31:12 INFO  CachingConnectionFactory:463 - Created new connection: consumerConnectionFactory#3b19c93a:0/SimpleConnection@192009f5 [delegate=amqp://rabbituser@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 64642]`

That is what I see in the log file.

Comment: So you need to figure out how you have 2 connection factories with, apparently, the same bean name, which shouldn't be possible unless you have 2 application contexts. You can also set a breakpoint in `AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection()` to figure out what's using the second factory. I will be offline until tomorrow (US EDT).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173506/discussion-between-rajeev-k-and-gary-russell).

Comment: Russel : You were right about '2 application contexts'. We had `<mvc:annotation-driven /><context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.*" />` in the `servlet-context.xml` and we also had `<context:annotation-config /><context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.*"/>` in application-context.xml. I suspect one of these is redudent and is the root cause of the issue. I moved the `<mvc:annotation-driven /><context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.*" />` to application-context.xml and got rid of everything else and that seems to do the trick. Once again thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java Configuration for creating SimpleMessageListenerContainer

```
@Value("#{'${queue.names}'.split(',')}")
private String[] queueNames;

 @Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queueNames);
    container.setMessageListener(vehiclesReceiver());
    setCommonQueueProperties(container);
    return container;
}
```

Comment: Hi Raghvendra, thx for sharing your configuration. If I do mine this way with (exclusive mode and concurrent consumers =1) I would end up having a single connection with 1 channel for all my queues. Where as with the XML configuration, I would get 1 connection with a dedicated channel per queue. I want the Java configuration to do exactly that.

Comment: See my answer, please

Answer (score 1):

Each `<rabbit:listener >` creates its own `SimpleListenerContainer` bean with the same `ConnectionFactory`. To do similar in Java config, you have to declare as much `SimpleListenerContainer` beans as you have queues: one for each of them.

You also may consider to use `@RabbitListener` approach instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven

Comment: I could definitely create as many 'SimpleListenerContainer''s as necessary IF I knew the queue names ahead of time. In my case, I get is as a comma separated string from the configuration file. What I want is a dedicated channel for each queue. If you see my original question, that is what I was trying to do in the `@PostConstruct` loop. It does not work with out forcing the `messageListenerContainer(queue).start();`. Even then it is not perfect because it openes a second connectio which is not expected. How do I create as many 'SimpleListenerContainer' 's as necessary?

Comment: You can't start in the `@PostConstruct` - that's too early. You need to implement `SmartLifecycle` and iterate over there in its `start()` implementation. You can make that your `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` as a `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` and really call it with the desired queue name in the loop. But again: that must not happen in the `@PostConstruct`. Also you should be sure that you use a `CachingConnectionFactory` which used `CacheMode.CHANNEL` by default, so you will really have only a single `connection` there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will give `SmartLifecycle` a go and report back. That said, I am still lost why I even have to do this at the first place? Why does the Java configuration NOT allow the same thing that was possible in the XML configuration? I know `<rabbit:listener-container/>` with multiple `<rabbit:listener/>` is a convenient way to specify common container attributes for each container created by the child elements. I have seen Gary's answer to a different question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629152/spring-boot-multiple-rabbitmq-listeners-to-single-container)

Comment: Wait. Your main requirement is to be able to split the property via comma. That isn't going to be possible with XML at all. Well, common properties can come via common `private` method for all other container `@Bean` definitions, but still that doesn't look like your original requirement.

Comment: I have added a detailed Business Case to my original question. That should help clear up what I am trying to do and why?

Comment: Well, you know you are overcomplicating things arguing what is possible and what not. Nobody says that something really can be missed, but you can't also advocate for XML configuration since it really does not support loops.

Comment: Now let's try to imaging if there is any out-of-the-box solution for your splitting use-case in Spring at all. And well, there is no easy way. And we really suggest you solution via a `SmartLifecycle` and a `prototype` `@Bean`. What's wrong with that? All the bean definitions in Spring typically are static declaration. That's how it isn't so convenient for all use-cases, but still we can come up with the solution even if it isn't an out-of-the-box feature. What am I missing here?